# "Could not import bootstrap model" when trying to package with Alfresco Maven SDK

Tags: java, spring, maven, alfresco

I'm trying to package an AMP (Alfresco Module Package) with some custom datalists for Alfresco Community. When I launch integration tests, all works fine, but when I try to package it, all I get is an error log with lots of Spring exceptions.

The principal exception is this:

```
org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 07220001 Could not import bootstrap model
```

And this is my boostrap bean:

```
<bean id="customdatalist-repo.dictionaryBootstrap" parent="dictionaryModelBootstrap" depends-on="dictionaryBootstrap">
    <property name="models">
        <list>
            <value>alfresco/module/${project.artifactId}/model/content-model.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <!-- LABELS -->
    <property name="labels">
        <list>
            <value>alfresco/module/${project.artifactId}/messages/datalist-model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm following the *[Datalist Development guide](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/references/dev-extension-points-data-lists.html)* at the Alfresco Docs

**UPDATE**
Test results.

```
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 43.469 sec <<< FAILURE! - in customdatalist.demoamp.test.DemoComponentTest
testChildNodesCount(customdatalist.demoamp.test.DemoComponentTest)  Time elapsed: 27.794 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customdatalist-repo.dictionaryBootstrap' defined in class path resource [alfresco/module/customdatalist-repo/context/bootstrap-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 07220001 Could not import bootstrap model 'alfresco/module/customdatalist-repo/model/content-model.xml'
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 07220001 Could not import bootstrap model 'alfresco/module/customdatalist-repo/model/content-model.xml'
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 07220000 Failed to compile model 'acmedl:datalistModel'
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceException: URI http://www.alfresco.org/model/datalist/1.0 cannot be imported as it is not defined (with prefix dl

testWiring(customdatalist.demoamp.test.DemoComponentTest)  Time elapsed: 8.805 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customdatalist-repo.dictionaryBootstrap' defined in class path resource [alfresco/module/customdatalist-repo/context/bootstrap-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 07220003 Could not import bootstrap model 'alfresco/module/customdatalist-repo/model/content-model.xml'
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 07220003 Could not import bootstrap model 'alfresco/module/customdatalist-repo/model/content-model.xml'
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 07220002 Failed to compile model 'acmedl:datalistModel'
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceException: URI http://www.alfresco.org/model/datalist/1.0 cannot be imported as it is not defined (with prefix dl

testGetCompanyHome(customdatalist.demoamp.test.DemoComponentTest)  Time elapsed: 6.431 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customdatalist-repo.dictionaryBootstrap' defined in class path resource [alfresco/module/customdatalist-repo/context/bootstrap-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 07220005 Could not import bootstrap model 'alfresco/module/customdatalist-repo/model/content-model.xml'
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 07220005 Could not import bootstrap model 'alfresco/module/customdatalist-repo/model/content-model.xml'
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 07220004 Failed to compile model 'acmedl:datalistModel'
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceException: URI http://www.alfresco.org/model/datalist/1.0 cannot be imported as it is not defined (with prefix dl
```

Stacktrace.

```
Running customdatalist.demoamp.test.DemoComponentTest
2016-08-22 14:46:08,655  WARN  [alfresco.util.RuntimeSystemPropertiesSetter] [main] Could not find alfresco-jmxrmi.password on classpath
 2016-08-22 14:46:08,825  INFO  [alfresco.repo.admin] [main] Using database URL 'jdbc:h2:/home/juanjo/Documentos/test-sdk/test-repo/customdatalist-project/customdatalist-repo/alf_data_dev/h2_data/alf_dev;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;MVCC=FALSE;LOCK_MODE=0' with user 'alfresco'.
 2016-08-22 14:46:09,720  INFO  [alfresco.repo.admin] [main] Connected to database H2 version 1.4.190 (2015-10-11)
 2016-08-22 14:46:18,074  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [main] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V4.2-metadata-query-indexes
 2016-08-22 14:46:18,074  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [main] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V5.1-metadata-query-indexes
 2016-08-22 14:46:31,391  WARN  [context.support.GenericApplicationContext] [main] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customdatalist-repo.dictionaryBootstrap' defined in class path resource [alfresco/module/customdatalist-repo/context/bootstrap-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 07220001 Could not import bootstrap model 'alfresco/module/customdatalist-repo/model/content-model.xml'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:102)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:69)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at com.tradeshift.test.remote.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 07220001 Could not import bootstrap model 'alfresco/module/customdatalist-repo/model/content-model.xml'
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.DictionaryBootstrap.onDictionaryInit(DictionaryBootstrap.java:173)
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.DictionaryBootstrap.bootstrap(DictionaryBootstrap.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 07220000 Failed to compile model 'acmedl:datalistModel'
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.CompiledModel.<init>(CompiledModel.java:116)
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.M2Model.compile(M2Model.java:167)
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.DictionaryDAOImpl.putModelImpl(DictionaryDAOImpl.java:273)
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.DictionaryDAOImpl.putModel(DictionaryDAOImpl.java:260)
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.DictionaryBootstrap.onDictionaryInit(DictionaryBootstrap.java:169)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceException: URI http://www.alfresco.org/model/datalist/1.0 cannot be imported as it is not defined (with prefix dl
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.CompiledModel.createLocalPrefixResolver(CompiledModel.java:214)
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.CompiledModel.constructDefinitions(CompiledModel.java:138)
    at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.CompiledModel.<init>(CompiledModel.java:96)
    ... 54 more
```

And my `content-model.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<model name="acmedl:datalistModel" xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0">

    <!-- Optional meta-data about the model -->
    <description>Seyte DataList test</description>
    <author>Juanjo Salvador</author>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <imports>
        <!-- Import Alfresco Dictionary Definitions -->
        <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d"/>
        <!-- Import Alfresco Content Domain Model Definitions -->
        <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm"/>
        <!-- Import Alfresco Data List Model Definitions -->
        <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/datalist/1.0" prefix="dl" />
    </imports>

    <!-- Custom namespace for the ACME company Data Lists-->
    <namespaces>
        <namespace uri="http://www.acme.org/model/datalist/1.0" prefix="acmedl"/>
    </namespaces>

    <types>
        <!--
            Data List Item Type for the custom project list
            -->
        <type name="acmedl:projectListItem">
            <title>DataList Seyte</title>
            <parent>dl:dataListItem</parent>
            <properties>
                <property name="acmedl:projectName">
                    <type>d:text</type>
                    <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                </property>
                <property name="acmedl:projectDescription">
                    <type>d:text</type>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </type>
    </types>
</model>
```

Comment: Could you please show us the whole stacktrace ?

Comment: @Akah, yeah,  updated.

Comment: I would need your content-model.xml file. It is possible that you are using datalist but you didn't included <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/datalist/1.0" prefix="dl"/>

Comment: @Akah, it is included. It's a Maven package.

Comment: I would still need your content-model.xml file.

Comment: Updated with `content-model.xml` @Akah

Comment: Could you please show us a sample of your test ? (The head of the class, and one of the failing unit test)

Comment: The three tests are failing and there are posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is not the best way** to do this, but looking for a fix, I decided to skip the tests because my package doen't compile by the failed tests.

Solution was:

```
mvn clean
mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

And install both packages (share and repo) using `alfresco-mnt.jar`

```
java -jar bin/alfresco-mnt.jar install <repo package> tomcat/webapps/alfresco.war
java -jar bin/alfresco-mnt.jar install <share package> tomcat/webapps/share.war
```

Now is done. But remember, **THIS IS NOT THE BEST WAY**.

Comment: I have the same issue. mvn clean install throws the same datalist uri not found error. Your solution worked for me but I agree this is not the best way. Did you maybe find another solution to this issue?